# function calls python (pygames)

Tags: python, pygame

So what i am trying to do is have a set of methods where i can add objects such as a character, make it move and display some text all on the same window. This is what i have

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

def get_font():
    game_font = pygame.font.Font(None,30)

def screen(width,height,name):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
    return window

def name(name="", array=[]):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 15)
    label = myfont.render(name, 1, (255,255,0))
    result=screen(640,480,name).blit(label, (100, 100))
    array.append(name)
    pygame.display.update()
    return name

def drawCharacter(array=[]):
    initialise()
    character = pygame.image.load("resources/images/character.png")
    drawcharacter = window(640,480,character).blit(character, (100, 400))
    array.append(character)
    pygame.display.update()
    return drawcharacter



name("akunama tata pig")
drawCharacter()

while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
     pygame.display.update()
```

here it is just displaying the character, no text but i dont understand why. Ive tried adding them to an array and display them like that. but no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: afaik you are creating a new screen with each call ... you probably want to call `myscreen = screen(width,height)` and then reuse that screen .... but im not sure

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406467/calling-functions-python-pygame

Comment: not really, i have a different problem, before nothing was displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this myself: I defined

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
```

at the start and reused this.